# My hover is not working despite doing almost the same line of code from my other website

Tags: html, css, hover

So basically, I want to have a hover effect on my links. My past websites has their :hover working but this time it does not. I don't know what broke on my code but this is how I usually set them up. I try the web inspector in order to add the effect with the same line of code and it worked. Please help.

my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clay Romero</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css"/>
</head>


<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>Author Name</h1>

            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">Books</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <img src="./images/newBook.png" alt="Book Model"/>
            <h2 class="book-title">BOOK TITLE</h2>
            <h4 class="sub-text">My new book, <i>"This is A Book Title"</i> has just been released</h4> 

        </div>
    </header>

<main>

</main>

</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bodoni+Moda:wght@800&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("./images/Background-Asset.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
}
header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}
header nav h1 {
  font-family: "Bodoni Moda", serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
header nav ul li {
  padding: 0 3rem;
}
header nav ul li a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}
header nav ul li a a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

I tried everything from putting it on an inline or block display or even making chnaging z-index, Nothing worked. And I even tried putting the hover effect on the logo and it didnt work too.

Comment: You have to remove a a and also changes the color so you can check that its working or not. Please check this pen  https://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/eYLVKpQ

Comment: @Leothelion Thank you so much for the replication and correction!! This really had me stuck for hours. I was supposed to even re do the whole thing! I blame the Sass compiler for this. This wouldn't happened if I did with just plain CSS. Thank you! I will get back to y'all if it fixed it and I trust yall!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `a a:hover` which will apply the styling to the link within the link, so remove one `a`, do as following

```
header nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

**for sass**

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
      li {
        display: inline-block;
        
        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            &:hover {
                background: #fff;
            }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

use `&` operator to apply the styling on hover. You might be using `a:hover` with in `a`.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH. I knew that was the problem. I was using SCSS to complile them and usually i don't encounter this problem and I thought that it's just how it's supposed to look like. Scss compiled it wrongly. So Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: Can I also add on how to correctly do pseudo elements on sass?? Like how do i properly place them when I nest things? I think this was a mistake when I did the hover class. And also the ::after class.

Comment: i have edited the answer according to sass.

Answer (score 2):

```
Please change your CSS.
you can use double "a" in your CSS code. 
put only one a:hover like this following code.

.header nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized it too late on why it wont work. The scss compiler wronly coded this for me so thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think double "a" was the reason in your CSS code.
Can you try like the following?

```
header nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra `a` from your CSS:

```
header nav ul li  a:hover {
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```